# The shop has opened today vs the shop opened today

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

What is the difference between those:

- The shop has opened today
- The shop opened today
- The shop has been opened today
- The shop was opened today

Comment: [difference between these or the sentences below]. Do you mean open for the first time or not?

Answer (score 1):

Without context, it's hard to know exactly what the speaker/author means. So, without context, here's how I would interpret it.

> The shop has opened today

Someone that works at the shop has opened it for the day, more than likely at its opening hour. (Maybe the shop's hours are 8am-7pm and the worker came in so it would be open for business at 8)

> The shop opened today

The shop is either brand new or has been closed for a while (renovations or something), but is now open.

> The shop has been opened today

Could be either 1 or 2.

> The shop was opened today

Could be interpreted as either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the explanation you're looking for but I'll explain the tenses.

The shop has opened today means the shop is now open. The focus is on the present result. Present perfect tense is possible because today hasn't finished yet.

The shop opened today: past simple is used because you consider the opening of the shop as something that happened in the past and the focus is on the past. For example the shop opened at 9 in the morning and you speak about it at 3 in the afternoon.

The other two examples are passive, meaning the shop has been/was opened by someone.

Answer (score 1):

Generally we say **The shop is open or closed today**.

But **the shop has been opened for the first time today**.

**The exhibition will be  officially opened by the Prime Minister Tomorrow**.

**The shop was open in the morning but it was closed  in the evening**.

It is not clear inwhich sense you are asking

I here  with  attach a link to  make things  clear.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/opened